# Esplanade theme - WordPress - Responsive design

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, sidebar

I want to when screen resolution less eg. 960px, left and right sidebar don't move down, below content div. On 960px width resolution, content div is width 100%, I don't want this, I want to all reduce proportionately and right and left sidebar stay in the same place how can see on bigger resolution.

Answer (score 0):

check your style.css file. there must be css media queries for that. If you can show me the code I can help you.Cant help without see anything.